# Eclipse build path android error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, buildpath

After importing a project from GIT using clone it failed to run. The android library in the build path is missing. How do I get it back?

[image]

I can't fix the problem with answers already given on other similar questions. Reinstalling eclipse doesn't help.

Also, I can't find the project.properties, which had something to do with this problem.

After trying to clean this project:

[image]

Hope someone can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved! But I don't really know what it solved. This is what I did:

- Delete eclipse and workspace with project
- Download new eclipse ADT bundle
- Git clone project in new workspace
- Project files from git in NEW workspace map, seperated from git files (!)
- Start Eclipse in workspace with project files
- Import Android code (NOT existing project into workspace)
- It worked!